# Symfony 3 FOSUserBundle redirect to login after submiting edit profile

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

Here is my problem, im working with FOSUserBundle and Symfony 3, i've created a UserBundle that inherits FOSUserBundle so i can override some of it's parts when needed, for project's needs i've created two firewalls, one for the backend and the second for the frontend part, everything worked fine until i tried to edit the current logged user's profile(username and email), when i use var_dump($this->getUser()) while loading the editing form i get all of the current user's data but after submiting i get var_dump($this->getUser()) = null and get redirected to login form.

This is the security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /admin/
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:         /admin/login
        anonymous:    true
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            check_path:     /login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:
            path:           /logout
            target:         /login

    anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The routes for the admin(backend) part in routing.yml:

```
admin_login:
    path:  /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

admin_check:
    path:  /admin/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

admin_logout:
    path:  /admin/logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }

admin_profile_show:
    path:  /admin/profile/show
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:show }

admin_profile_edit:
    path:  /admin/profile/edit
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit }

admin_profile_change_password:
    path:  /admin/profile/changePassword
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword }
```

And this is the editAction in my ProfileController.php that can be accessed via the route `admin_profile_edit` in the routing file above, that action overrides the one in FOSUserBundle

```
// UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php 
public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        $requestAttributes = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentrequest()->attributes;
        if ($requestAttributes->get('_route') == 'admin_profile_edit') {
            $template = sprintf('UserBundle:Profile:user_admin_edit.html.twig');
        } else {
            $template = sprintf('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->render($template, array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Now when loading the editing form everything works fine and the current user data  show perfectly if i use var_dump($this->getUser()), but after submiting the form  the same var_dump is null and im redirected to the login form.

I don't know if im missing somthing or doing it wrong, because i've already did the same thing with another project in Symfony 2.8 and it worked perfectly without any problems.

I hope that i've provided the max informations for my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is  to change the form action from `fos_user_profile_edit` to `admin_profile_edit`, the route that loaded the edit form was `admin_profile_edit` for **the backend users**, but i've forgot to change it in my **form action** that's why after submitting the user wasn't reconized anymore because it was redirected to the `fos_user_profile_edit` editAction that is supposed to work in the frontend part.

Answer (score 0):

Extend base Action(login), and add custom logic with `redirect`; 
See [Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html):

This redirects using a 301 return code to the client:

```
$this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl(
        'person_in_need_view',
        array('id' => $id)
    )
);
```

This redirects internally:

```
$this->forward(
    'person_in_need_view',
    array('id' => $id)
)
```

Comment: I found the problem,
Like i suspected i forgot to change the form action in my editing form i just changed de route `fos_user_profile_edit` to `admin_profile_edit`

Anyway thank you for your response.